# Default http connections that can be opened in solr 4.3 concurrently

Tags: solr, solrj, solr4

I am using singleton HttpSolrServer in my application. I want to know how many http connections that can be opened concurrently and how can I configure this

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on what implementation of `HttpClient` you're using, and how you've configured it.

If you're not creating HttpSolrServer with your own, instanced HttpClient, SolrJ creates an `org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient` for you, [with the following settings](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.solr/solr-solrj/4.10.2/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/HttpSolrServer.java/#164):

```
  params.set(HttpClientUtil.PROP_MAX_CONNECTIONS, 128);
  params.set(HttpClientUtil.PROP_MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOST, 32);
  params.set(HttpClientUtil.PROP_FOLLOW_REDIRECTS, followRedirects);
```

You can change this by creating the `HttpClient` yourself and providing it in the SolrJ constructor.

Comment: Many Thanks. I have to integrate solr with liferay. Liferay is interanlly instantiating HttpSolrServer -this._server = new HttpSolrServer(this._url, defaultHttpClient);
  this._poolingClientConnectionManager = new PoolingClientConnectionManager();

    DefaultHttpClient defaultHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(
      this._poolingClientConnectionManager);